# R - creating diverse links for rvest to use

Tags: r, dplyr, data-mining, rvest, stringi

I've encountered a problem with creating proper links to use for data mining later .
Let's say the link should look like this:
*[www.domain.com/city/month/week](http://www.domain.com/city/month/week)* .
Each of the data (City, Month etc) is a vector. Cities are Strings, months and weeks are numbers [1:12] and [1:5].
My goal is to create links with every possible combination of Cities, Months and Weeks
(so for example:

```
[1] www.domain.com/Denver/1/1, 
[2] www.domain.com/Denver/1/2, 
[3] www.domain.com/Denver/1/3,
........ 
[53] www.domain.com/Denver/10/3
........
[2823]www.domain.com/Phoenix/12/5
```

and so on)

I bet there's a simple solution I haven't thought about.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
eg <- expand.grid(
  host = "www.domain.com",
  city = c("Denver", "Phoenix"),
  month = 1:2,
  week = 1:3)
eg
#              host    city month week
# 1  www.domain.com  Denver     1    1
# 2  www.domain.com Phoenix     1    1
# 3  www.domain.com  Denver     2    1
# 4  www.domain.com Phoenix     2    1
# 5  www.domain.com  Denver     1    2
# 6  www.domain.com Phoenix     1    2
# 7  www.domain.com  Denver     2    2
# 8  www.domain.com Phoenix     2    2
# 9  www.domain.com  Denver     1    3
# 10 www.domain.com Phoenix     1    3
# 11 www.domain.com  Denver     2    3
# 12 www.domain.com Phoenix     2    3

do.call(paste, c(eg, sep = "/"))
#  [1] "www.domain.com/Denver/1/1"  "www.domain.com/Phoenix/1/1"
#  [3] "www.domain.com/Denver/2/1"  "www.domain.com/Phoenix/2/1"
#  [5] "www.domain.com/Denver/1/2"  "www.domain.com/Phoenix/1/2"
#  [7] "www.domain.com/Denver/2/2"  "www.domain.com/Phoenix/2/2"
#  [9] "www.domain.com/Denver/1/3"  "www.domain.com/Phoenix/1/3"
# [11] "www.domain.com/Denver/2/3"  "www.domain.com/Phoenix/2/3"
```